# Getting cursor.close() UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment error while calling /api/view/addmin

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, rest, flask, flask-restful

This is the code in which I am getting error .Same operation is achieved by using SQLAlchemy  but WHen I am writing it in mysql then I am getting error.

```
    import pymysql
    from functools import  wraps
    import jwt
    import uuid
    import  datetime
    from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
    from app import app
    from config import mysql
    from flask import jsonify
    from flask import flash, request
    app.config['SECRET_KEY']='confidential'
    
    def token_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated(*args,**kwargs):
            token= None
            if 'x-acess-token' in request.headers:
                token=request.headers['x-acess-token']
            if not  token:
                return  jsonify("token not found")
            try:
                data=jwt.decode(token,app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
                conn=mysql.connect()
                cursor=conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
                cursor.execute('select  * from hireme_emp  where id=%s',data['id'])
                current_user=cursor.fetchone()
            except:
                return jsonify('invalid token')
            finally:
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
            return  f(current_user,*args,**kwargs)
        return decorated

#-----------------------------------------------

    app.route('/api/view/addmin')
    @token_required
    def view_addmin(current_user):
        try:
            conn=mysql.connect()
            cursor=conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM hireme_emp WHERE admin=1")
            rows=cursor.fetchall()
            resp=jsonify(rows)
            resp.status_code=200
            return  resp
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
```

This is the code when I am running this endpoint without token then it is giving "token not found" message but when I send token it is displaying this error i.e (

```
ERROR :line 30, in decorated
    cursor.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2021 01:08:53] "GET /api/view/addmin HTTP/1.1" 500 -.
```

Actually below code performs same job using  SQLAlchemy and is working .I am just trying to rewrite this code using pure mysql but i am not understanding where i am getting wrong. Thanks in advance for helping

```
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = None

        if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
            token = request.headers['x-access-token']

        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message' : 'Token is missing!'}), 401

        try: 
            data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
            current_user = User.query.filter_by(public_id=data['public_id']).first()
        except:
            return jsonify({'message' : 'Token is invalid!'}), 401

        return f(current_user, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

Answer (score 1):

define conn and cursor before you start the try catch

Further your working code shows you using public_id not id

I also change the code cursor.execute to tuples

```
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args,**kwargs):
        token= None
        if 'x-acess-token' in request.headers:
            token=request.headers['x-acess-token']
        if not  token:
            return  jsonify("token not found")
            
        conn=mysql.connect()
        cursor=conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        try:
            data=jwt.decode(token,app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
            cursor.execute('select  * from hireme_emp  where id=%s LIMIT 1',(data['public_id'],))
            current_user=cursor.fetchone()
        except:
            return jsonify('invalid token')
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
        return  f(current_user,*args,**kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Comment: Thanks ,Now its working  but now there is problem in my code  whenever i am sending curl -X GET \
  http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/view/addmin \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'postman-token: f2ebac7c-b390-3b41-414a-69eca941e2e7' \
  -H 'x-acess-token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6OCwiZXhwIjoxNjI3MDEwNDE5fQ.CD_ZgZdWJ3NevIpGDflTVOuzlAIIdg4MUtr_rwnQyto'    -----------                                                                               it is executing except part and giving response invalid token though i have created fresh token. please help

Comment: That you must debug line by line  especially the part of themysql , you also can enable general log on mysql server and see what the server receives